# Program attiny13 with Arduino uno 1.6

Tags: core-libraries

I am looking for the boards.txt, platform.txt and core files needed for the programming of the ATtiny13 with the Arduino Uno. Those I find on the internet probably only works with Arduino 1.0 and not with 1.6.

Comment: Have you tried porting them yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library for IDE 1.6 https://github.com/damellis/attiny/

Comment: Except for the fact that it lacks support for the '13, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I already did, but this files are only for the ATTiny 44-45-84 and 85 and the ATtiny 13 is not supported.